# Развертывание django приложения на проде

Tags: python, django, centos

Пытаюсь впервые развернуть django-приложение на проде. Раньше только писал их локально и запускал через runserver, но вот разворачивать на сервере не доводилось... Много перегуглил, как я понял есть несколько вариантов: heroku (мне вроде не очень подходит), gunicorn (еще не понял что это такое...), и uwsgi. Остановился пока на последнем варианте. Делаю по [этой](https://habrahabr.ru/post/226419/) статье. Все установил, пытаюсь запустить:

`uwsgi --http 0.0.0.0:8000 --module=core.wsgi:application`

Но сервер недоступен. Что еще можно сделать?

P.S. Сервер обычный, не VPS. На нем стоит CentOS 6.9, Apache, Nginx и IPSManager (пока что тут только PHP-сайты хостились).

Comment: У вас перед `http` стоит тире вместо дефиса. И перед `module` тоже

Comment: @andreymal спасибо, не заметил. Запустилось, но адрес по которому должен быть сайт (добавлен в IPSManager) все равно не доступен. :(

Comment: Тут кто-нибудь есть? Актуально, помогите пожалуйста, второй день мучаюсь!!! Пробовал и через gunicorn - все та же фигня - недоступен и все тут. Уже не знаю что пробовать - ничего не помогает.

Comment: Судя по тому, что `--http 0.0.0.0:8000` в статье вообще не существует — вы от неё отклоняетесь. Поэтому сразу же требуется больше подробностей: кто такой «сервер обычный», какой адрес вы пытаетесь открывать, используете ли nginx или открываете напрямую, пишет ли uwsgi что-нибудь в логах?

Comment: @andreymal Я комбинирую информацию из разных статей. Просто запуск как в статье с `--http :8000` тоже не работает. Насколько я понял он запускает сервак на локалхосте вообще по умолчанию, поэтому 0.0.0.0 надо чтобы сервер был доступен снаружи.

Comment: «просто какая-то машина» может и не подоходить, потому что, например, она может оказаться за роутером с NAT, или фаервол может мешать подключению, или ещё какая-нибудь дребедень. Если вы попробуете запустить без uwsgi `manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` — оно работает или нет?

Comment: 1. Ну это просто какая-то машина с поднятым линуксом к которой я подключаюсь по ssh. Я имею ввиду что у нас все просто, ни VPS, ни докера ни виртуалок там каких-то...

2. Открываю тот адрес который установлен в IPSManager (вполне себе реальный домен).

3. Я честно не знаю что там используется. Nginx или что... Я знаю что и Nginx и Apache на сервере стоят. Просто я никогда не поднимал реально проекты на проде, а запускал через runserver локально (для этого не нужен ни nginx ни апач). Не разбираюсь...

4. Если скажете где посмотреть логи я вам скажу что там есть.

Comment: @andreymal нет, пока у меня не получалось никак сделать чтобы сервер было видно снаружи. Ну а локально то понятное дело проект работает, я на своем ПК же его разрабатывал и все работало.

Comment: Мне всё ещё кажется, что это ваша «просто какая-то машина» кривая и дело вообще не в питонах. Если вы попробуете запустить на сервере что-то типа `nc -l -p 8989` (если такая команда есть или её возможно установить) и потом в браузере открыть что-то типа `http://ваша-простая-машина:8989/` — напишет ли nc что-то типа `GET / HTTP/1.1`? Если да, значит что-то не так в питонах всё-таки, если нет — то разбирайтесь в «вашей машиной» как-то иначе)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71920/discussion-between-dark-byte-and-andreymal).