# Проблема со статикой

Tags: python, django, nginx, centos, развертывание

Продолжаю [тему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/772416/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-django-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5) развертывания приложения джанго на проде. Мне удалось устранить большинство ошибок, сейчас основная проблема - не грузится статика. В настройках прописал:

```
DEBUG = False
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/static/' # python manage.py collectstatic делал

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    STATIC_ROOT
]
```

Также не уверен насчет урлов. Надо или нет?

```
static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Вроде в доках написано что в проде не использовать это, раздавать через nginx. Причем когда я это добавляю (с выключенным дебагом) у меня 500 ошибка, поэтому я убрал этот урл. Настройки нжинкса:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myhost.ru;

    access_log /var/www/sup78user/data/www/myhost.ru/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /var/www/sup78user/data/www/myhost.ru/logs/nginx-error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000; 
        proxy_set_header Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /var/www/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /var/www/media/;
    }
}
```

Сейчас грузится сайт, но полностью без статики. На статику 404 ругается. Не знаю уж что еще это может быть... Может с правами что не так?

```
ls -l /var/www/static
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Jan 23 11:33 admin
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan 23 11:33 js
```

Не уверен как оно должно быть... Но когда делал collectstatic - все скопировалось без проблем сюда.

P.S. CentOS 6.9, Apache, Nginx. Для старта использую теперь gunicorn. Почему-то с ним все куда проще и лучше работает, а вот с uwsgi нет...

Comment: `location /static/ { root /var/www; }`

Comment: @norbornen это абсолютно тоже самое. И да, так тоже не работает.

Comment: В логах nginx что пишет-то? Он там обязательно упоминает, почему именно случилась ошибка 404

Comment: @andreymal вот что меня удивляет - логи абсолютно пустые. У меня же вон в конфиге указаны файлы в проекте куда должны они писаться - так вот там пусто. Ни строчки.

Comment: @DarkByte а если `error_log [путь] warn;`

Comment: @andreymal все равно пусто.

Comment: А теперь уже просто не верю, потому что у меня при таком error_log nginx старательно сообщает обо всех ненайденных файлах (впрочем, он даже без warn должен сообщать). Возможно, вы что-то не договариваете, но пока я не знаю что. Попробую гадание по скриншоту: можно скриншот ошибки 404 в браузере?

Comment: @andreymal Зачем мне что-то недоговарировать? Я хочу уже разобраться с этим... Вот скриншот https://s.mail.ru/KWVa/i99z2Kdz5

Comment: @andreymal Кстати при попытке входа кидает 500 ошибку, хотя логин/пароль верные и база есть. Ну да ладно, я бы разобрался если бы были логи... А вот почему они не пишутся мне тоже крайне интересно.

Comment: @DarkByte а при чём тут вообще nginx, если вы сайт открываете через порт 8000 в обход этого самого nginx?

Comment: @DarkByte или же вы неправильно генерируете ссылки на статику, раз в ссылках торчит порт 8000. В общем, вы точно что-то не договариваете :)

Comment: @andreymal Почему вы думаете что он открывается в обход нжинкса? Как же тогда он вообще открывается если не через нжинкс?

Comment: @DarkByte а это я вас спрашиваю ;) На скриншоте, который вы показали, торчит порт 8000. nginx, согласно вашим же настройкам, использует порт 80. Откуда 8000 тогда там взялся — это вы должны нам рассказать :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72096/discussion-between-dark-byte-and-andreymal).

Comment: Будем ждать профи по настройке нжинкса. Магия же творится!